# Getting "uninitialized constant Zookeeper (NameError)" while trying to use zookeeper gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to use [zookeeper gem](http://github.com/wickman/zookeeper) and example code from README fails:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zookeeper'
z = Zookeeper.new("localhost:2181")
z.get_children(:path => "/")
```

causes error:

```
./zookeeper.rb:3: uninitialized constant Zookeeper (NameError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
 from zookeeper.rb:2
```

I'm googling and looking code and I really have no idea what to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call your file zookeeper.rb .

Comment: To clarify: When you use `require 'zookeeper'`, it is requiring your file, rather than requiring the zookeeper gem.  This is because, in Rubies less than 1.9.2, "." is at the end of the load path.